# referencing a jquery library from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Is there a way I can reference a jquery library from code behind , in the master page.

This is because  I only want to use jquery on aspx pages that need to use them. Currently
I have my jquery reference in the form tag and it gets loaded on every page load.

```
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerService" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ScriptMode="Auto" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js" ScriptMode="Auto" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" ScriptMode="Auto" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Just FYI, browser caches those CDN js files.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17577612/791952. You can use `ClientScriptManager` class similarly.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to reference external JS file in content pages, you can use [ScriptManagerProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanagerproxy.aspx) control. It will act pretty much like ScriptManager, but won't confilct with ScriptManager of the Master Page